# Fontawesomefx is showing a blank jar page

Tags: javafx, font-awesome, scenebuilder

I'm trying to add fontawesomefx to my Javafx project I'm using Scene Builder and Intellij, I did everything that is mentioned in any tutorial on the web, but only when choosing the fontawesomefx-fontawesome jar it shows a blank page on the jars list, also the import icon says "Import Jars(no UI components)" ...
other components are installed like the common.jar but I still can't use it.

[image: f]

Comment: same problem i got, couldn't get a solution yet